# Proof that a finite poset is uniquely determined by its cover relation

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, order-theory

**My proof:**

It is enough to show that if two partial orders on a finite set satisfy the same cover relation, then they must be the same order.

Let, $X$ is a finite set, and $\le_1$ and $\le_2$ be two partial orders on $X$ satisfying the same cover relation $\lt_c$. If possible, let $\le_2$ be distinct from $\le_1$, that is, $\exists a,b \in X, a\lt_2b, a\nless_1b$.

$a\lt_cb \implies a\lt_1b$, a contradiction, and so, $a\nless_cb$. Hence, $\exists x_1\in X, a\lt_2x_1\lt_2b$. By the same argument, $a\nless_cx_1$, and hence, $\exists x_2\in X, a\lt_2x_2\lt_2x_1$.

Hence, there are infinitely many elements $x_i \in X, a \lt_2 \dots \lt_2 x_2 \lt_2 x_1 \lt_2 b$. But this contradicts the assumption that $X$ is a finite set, and hence, $\le_1$ and $\le_2$ must be the same order.

Is the above proof correct?

PS: I am trying to learn combinatorics from Brualdi's "Introductory Combinatorics", and in chapter 4 this theorem is given as an exercise, with the hint to use transitivity. I don't see where transitivity can be used to prove this, so I'll appreciate it if somebody can give an hint regarding that.

Comment: Firstly, you must say assume that $a \neq b$. Also, $\neg(a <_c x_1)$ does not hold by the same argument. I believe you do not need to use method of contradiction. Just assume $a \leq _2 b$ and show that $a \leq_1 b$.

Comment: @Kaind Ah yes, I see was wrong in concluding $a \nless_cx_1$. As for $a \neq b$, I meant to type \lt, but made it \le by mistake.

Comment: @Aaratrick The result you mention naturally holds for a larger class of ordered sets (which includes the finite ones). I have supplied below a rather thorough proof for it so do take a look if you might still happen to be interested in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OP's notation.

**Claim 1**: $a \leq_2 b \land a \neq b \Rightarrow a \leq_1 b$.

Suppose $a <_c b$, then $a \leq_1 b$ and we are done. If not $\exists x_0$ s.t. $a <_2 x_0 <_2 b$ s.t. $x_0 <_c b$.

(If $x_0 \not<_c b$, then we can find $x_1$ s.t. $x_0 <_2 x_1 <_2 b$. If $x_1 \not<_c b$, then we can find $x_2$, and so on. As the set is finite, this process must terminate, and hence such an $x_0$ exists)

If $a \not<_c x_0$, then we similar to previous case we can find $x_1$ s.t. $a <_2 x_1 <_2 x_0$ s.t. $x_1 <_c x_0$. We can iterate this process. Again as the set is finite, this process must terminate, which implies $\exists \{x_i \; | 0 \leq i \leq N \}$ s.t. $a <_2 x_0 \land (\forall i) x_i <_2 x_{i+1} \land x_N <_2 b \land a <_c x_0 \land (\forall i) x_i <_c x_{i+1} \land x_N <_c b$. Thus $a <_1 x_0 \land (\forall i) x_i <_1 x_{i+1} \land x_N <_1 b$, and by the transitivity of a partial order, we have $a \leq_1 b$.

**Claim 2**: $a \leq_2 a \Rightarrow a \leq_1 a$ (holds by reflexivity)

These claims show that $\leq_2 \; \subseteq \; \leq_1$. By symmetry, $\leq_1 \; \subseteq \; \leq_2$ which implies that $\leq_2 \; = \; \leq_1$.

**Generalization**: From the above proof, we see that the above property holds true for even preorders, as we only require reflexivity and transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you are mentioning is quite remarkable and can be described in a more general fashion. Given arbitrary set $A$ let us write $\mathscr{Ord}(A)$ for the set of all order relations on $A$. For fixed order $R \in \mathscr{Ord}(A)$ we use the following notations:

- $x \leqslant_R y$ as an equivalent rendering of $xRy$ (or $(x, y) \in R$).
- $x<_R y$ as an equivalent rendering of $x \leqslant_R y \wedge x \neq y$ or $(x, y) \in R \setminus \Delta_A$.
- $(x, y)_R \colon=\{t \mid x <_R t <_R y\}$ for the open interval with respect to $R$ determined by $x$ and $y$, together with the analogous suggestive syntax for the other types of intervals: $[x, y]_R$, $[x, y)_R$, $(x, y]_R$, $(\leftarrow, y)_R$, $(\leftarrow, y]_R$, $(x, \rightarrow)_R$, $[x, \rightarrow)_R$.
- $\mathrm{Min}_R(X)$ for the set of all $R$-minimal elements of arbitrary subset $X \subseteq A$.
- $R_{\bullet}\colon=\{u \mid (\exists x, y)\left(u=(x, y) \wedge x<_Ry \wedge (x, y)_R=\varnothing\right)\}$ to denote the collection of all ordered pairs $(x, y)$ such that $y$ is a *successor* of $x$ with respect to $R$, in other words the so-called *covering* relation associated to $R$.
- $\{x\}^+_R \colon=\{y \mid x<_R y \wedge (x, y)_R=\varnothing\}$ ($\{x\}^-_R \colon=\{y \mid y<_R x \wedge (y, x)_R=\varnothing\}$) for the set of all *successors* (*predecessors*) of $x$ with respect to $R$. We note that $\{x\}^+_R=R_{\bullet}\langle x \rangle$ (respectively $\{x\}^-_R=\left(R_{\bullet}\right)^{-1}\langle x \rangle$).
- $\mathscr{Rel}(A)\colon=\mathscr{P}(A \times A)$ for the set of all binary relations on $A$.
- $[X]_{\mathrm{RefTr}}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X^{[n]}$ for the *reflexive-transitive closure* of arbitrary binary relation $X \subseteq A \times A$ (closure which is defined as the intersection of all the reflexive & transitive relations on $A$ which include $X$ or equivalently the *smallest* such (including $X$) reflexive & transitive relation on $A$ with respect to the order given by inclusion). $X^{[m]}$ denotes the composition of $X$ $m$ times with itself, or more rigorously speaking the power of exponent $m$ of $X$ with respect to the monoid $\left(\mathscr{Rel}(A), \circ\right)$ (the operation being the composition of binary relations).

Recall that given $R \in \mathscr{Ord}(A)$ we say the ordered set $(A, R)$ is *artinian* (*noetherian*) if any *nonempty* subset $X \subseteq A$ admits a minimal (maximal) element. The following are then equivalent statements regarding the ordered set $(A, R)$:

- $(A, R)$ is artinian (noetherian)
- *any* sequence $x \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ decreasing (increasing) with respect to $R$ is necessarily eventually stationary
- there exists no sequence $x \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ *strictly* decreasing (increasing) with respect to $R$.

Recall also **the fundamental theorem of recursion** in its following formulation: given arbitrary set $A$, fixed element $a \in A$ and self-map $f \colon A \to A$, there exists a *unique* sequence $u \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $u_0=a$ and $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We shall now establish the following:

> **Proposition.** Consider set $A$ and two orders $R, R' \in \mathscr{Ord}(A)$ such that $R_{\bullet} \subseteq R'_{\bullet}$. If the ordered set $(A, R)$ is simultaneously artinian and noetherian it holds that $R \subseteq R'$.

*Proof.* We first remark the relation:
$$\{x\}^+_R=R_{\bullet}\langle x \rangle \subseteq R'_{\bullet}\langle x \rangle=\{x\}^+_{R'},$$
in other words any $R$-successor of $x$ is automatically an $R'$-successor for any $x \in A$.

Let us proceed by *Reductio ad absurdum* and assume the contrary of what we must prove, namely that $R \setminus R' \neq \varnothing$. This means there exist $a, b \in A$ such that $a \leqslant_R b$ and nevertheless $(a, b) \notin R'$. Since $\Delta_A \subseteq R'$ by definition, it follows that $(a, b) \notin \Delta_A$ and hence that $a<_R b$. Furthermore, since $R_{\bullet} \subseteq R'_{\bullet} \subseteq R'$, it also must be that $(a, b) \notin R_{\bullet}$ whence in conjunction with $a<_R b$ we infer that necessarily $(a, b)_R \neq \varnothing$.

Fixing an arbitrary element $u \in A$, let us remark that for given $x \in (\leftarrow, u)_R$ we either have that $(x, u)_R=\varnothing$ - in which case $u$ itself is an $R$-*successor* of $x$ - or $(x, u)_R \neq \varnothing$, in which case *any* of the elements of the set $\mathrm{Min}_R\left((x, u)_R\right) \neq \varnothing$ - set nonempty by virtue of artinianity and the fact that $(x, u)_R \neq \varnothing$ - is once again an $R$-*successor* of $x$ at most equal to $u$ (actually in this case strictly less than $u$). By a so-called application of the axiom of choice we thus infer the existence of a map $\sigma \colon (\leftarrow, b)_R \to (\leftarrow, b]_R$ such that $\sigma(x) \in \{x\}^+_R$ for each $x<_R b$.

Let us move on to introducing the subset:
$$B \colon=\{x \in [a, b)_R \mid a \leqslant_{R'} x \wedge (x, b)_R \neq \varnothing\}=[a, \rightarrow)_{R'} \cap [a, b)_R \setminus \{b\}^-_R$$
and let us make the crucial observation that $\sigma[B] \subseteq B$ (this is the part where the hint regarding transitivity comes into play). Indeed, if $x \in B$ then by definition $a \leqslant_R x<_R b$ and $(x, b)_R \neq \varnothing$, which means that $\sigma(x) \neq b$. Hence we have $a \leqslant_R x <_R \sigma(x) <_R b$, which means that $\sigma(x) \in [a, b)_R$. Since by construction $\sigma(x) \in \{x\}^+_R$ we infer from our opening remark that $\sigma(x) \in \{x\}^+_{R'}$ and hence that $x \leqslant_{R'} \sigma(x)$. Bearing in mind that by definition of $B$ we also have $a \leqslant_{R'} x$, we infer from transitivity that $a \leqslant_{R'} \sigma(x)$ and hence $\sigma(x) \in [a, \rightarrow)_{R'}$.

We now only need to ascertain that $(\sigma(x), b)_R \neq \varnothing$ in order to conclude that $\sigma(x) \in B$. Assuming the contrary - that $(\sigma(x), b)=\varnothing$ - would mean in conjunction with the relation $\sigma(x)<_R b$ that $(\sigma(x), b) \in R_{\bullet} \subseteq R'_{\bullet} \subseteq R'$ and would eventually entail $a \leqslant_{R'} \sigma(x) \leqslant_{R'} b$, which once again by transitivity would amount to the absurd conclusion that $a \leqslant_{R'} b$.

Thus we can introduce the two-sided restriction $\varphi=_{B|}\sigma_{|B}$ which of course is a self-map $\varphi \colon B \to B$. Furthermore, it is clear that $a \in B$ and hence we can apply the fundamental theorem of recursion to the triplet $(B, a, \varphi)$ in order to infer the existence of sequence $c \in B^{\mathbb{N}}$ described by $c_0=a$ and $c_{n+1}=\varphi(c_n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since however $x <_R \sigma(x)$ for any $x<_R b$ from the preceding recursive definition we gather that $c_{n+1}=\sigma(c_n) >_R c_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This means that the sequence $c$ is strictly increasing with respect to $R$ which contradicts the fact that $(A, R)$ is noetherian, bringing our proof to an end. $\Box$

From this proposition it is easy to derive the following:

> **Corollary.** Let $\mathscr{Ord}_{\mathrm{AN}}(A)$ denote the set of all orders $R$ on $A$ such that $(A, R)$ is at the same time artinian and noetherian. Then the map given by:
> \begin{align}
> \mathscr{Ord}_{\mathrm{AN}}(A) &\to \mathscr{Rel}(A) \\
> R &\mapsto R_{\bullet}
> \end{align}
> is *injective*.

Another consequence which perhaps requires a bit more effort to prove but nevertheless essentially relies on the proposition above is:

> **Corollary.** Let $A$ be a set and $R \in \mathscr{Ord}_{\mathrm{AN}}(A)$. Then the relation $R=\left[R_{\bullet}\right]_{\mathrm{RefTr}}$ holds (in other words, any artinian & noetherian order relation can be recovered as the reflexive-transitive closure of its covering relation).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer, but I have to admit that this answer is, at the moment, out of my scope, as I have not studied posets or orders in very much detail. +1, because I could understand at least some ideas behind the deeper result.

Comment: @Aaratrick I am glad to hear it served in some measure to help your understanding. My goal was to show in detail how one sets up the recursive mechanism needed for producing the desired contradiction.